# FileMaker calculation to convert DMS latlong to decimal format

Tags: filemaker

I need a FileMaker "calculation" script to convert a DMS latlong (eg: `37°55'43.6"S, 145°11'26.1"E`) to a decimal format (eg: `-37.928778,145.190583`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fun way to do it: convert it to a FileMaker calculation and call `Evaluate()` on it.

```
Evaluate( 
  "Round(  (" &
  Substitute ( 
    dms ; 
    [" ";""] ; 
    ["°";" + "] ; 
    ["'";"/60 + "] ; 
    ["\"";"/3600"] ; 
    ["S";") *-1"] ; 
    ["W";") *-1"] ; 
    ["N";")"] ; 
    ["E";")"] ; 
    [","; " ; 6 ) & \",\" & Round( ("]
  ) & 
  " ; 6 )"
)
```

The above will turn the input into a calc like:

```
Round( (37 + 55/60 + 43.6/3600) *-1 ; 6 ) & "," & Round( (145 + 11/60 + 26.1/3600) ; 6 )
```

then passes that to `Evaluate`, which gives you `-37.928778,145.190583`

Comment: WOW! That my friend is very clever.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that uses the [`split()` custom function by David Snyder](http://www.briandunning.com/cf/45):

```
If ( IsEmpty(DMSLatlong);"";

    "-" & 

    Truncate(
        (
        Trim(split(
            Trim(split( DMSLatlong; 1; "," ))
        ; 1; "°" ))
        ) +

        (
        (
        Trim(split(
            Trim(split(
                Trim(split( DMSLatlong; 1; "," ))
            ; 1; "'" ))
        ; 2; "°" ))
        ) / 60
        ) +

        (
        (
        Trim(split(
            Trim(split(
                Trim(split( DMSLatlong; 1; "," ))
            ; 2; "'" ))
        ; 1; "\"" ))
        ) / 3600
        )
    ;7)


    & "," & 


    Truncate(
        (
        Trim(split(
            Trim(split( DMSLatlong; 2; "," ))
        ; 1; "°" ))
        ) +

        (
        (
        Trim(split(
            Trim(split(
                Trim(split( DMSLatlong; 2; "," ))
            ; 1; "'" ))
        ; 2; "°" ))
        ) / 60
        ) +

        (
        (
        Trim(split(
            Trim(split(
                Trim(split( DMSLatlong; 2; "," ))
            ; 2; "'" ))
        ; 1; "\"" ))
        ) / 3600
        )
    ;7)

)
```

Note: This script isn't bullet proof, and if DMS values are S or W, you may need to tweak it to put a `-` sign in front (as I have done above). Refer to: [Wikipedia: Conversion from Decimal Degree to DMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion#Conversion_from_Decimal_Degree_to_DMS).

Answer (score 0):

It could be as simple as =

```
Let ( [
v = Substitute ( DMS ; [ "°" ; ¶ ] ; [ "'" ; ¶ ] ; [ "\"" ; ¶ ] ) ;
t = Time ( GetValue ( v ; 1 ) ; GetValue ( v ; 2 ) ; GetValue ( v ; 3 ) ) ; 
h = GetValue ( v ; 4 ) 
] ;
If ( h = "S" or h = "W" ; -t ; t ) / 3600
)
```